# Difference between popular and overrated

Tags: word-usage

I noticed, people tend to have a confusion between the two words. Examples would help.

Comment: Examples would indeed help. Please supply some.

Comment: Hahaha, @Lawrence, such an overrated reply. Your popularity may suffer should you keep it up. I've always found that what's popular is often also overrated. Snapple, for instance, is basically juice flavored sugar water. I do not know why it's popularity befuddles me. Capri Sun is delicious however and essentially the same. While the definitions of the words differ, there certainly does seem to be some kind of duality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popular means:

> > adjective
> >     1.
> >     regarded with favor, approval, or affection by people in general:
> >     a popular preacher. (http://www.dictionary.com)

Basically, popular is favored and liked.

On the other hand overrated means

> > verb (used with object), overrated, overrating.
> >     1.
> >     to rate or appraise too highly; overestimate:
> >     [(www.dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/overrated?s=thttp://))

It most commonly means that something is way more liked and appreciated then it should be.

Comment: Too true however that what which is popular does tend to be overrated. :)

Comment: @Jesse Ivy -could not agree more as that is a really smart point. Popular has the meaning of what I listed above, yet popular nowadays is popular to some, and boring, bland, and overrated to others. I believe this is because everyone deemed popular does extremely similar things, thus making popular more and more overrated.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I've always felt that way. In style, for instance, it is not enough to follow the trends, one must set the trends to be stylish, ironically.